# Maximum number of service accounts in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a hard limit on the number of service accounts that can be created in  Kubernetes?

I couldn't find any documentation where this is stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the storage behind a service account registry, as coded in [`kubernetes/kubernetes/pkg/registry/core/serviceaccount`](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/pkg/registry/core/serviceaccount)

```
// storage puts strong typing around storage calls
type storage struct {
    rest.StandardStorage
}

// NewRegistry returns a new Registry interface for the given Storage. Any mismatched
// types will panic.
func NewRegistry(s rest.StandardStorage) Registry {
    return &storage{s}
}
```

A storage is a REST call to, for instance, [an ETCD storage](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/9bd4f12c336af339c35e773e1d71a37cad342f57/pkg/registry/core/serviceaccount/storage/storage_test.go#L33).

```
func newStorage(t *testing.T) (*REST, *etcdtesting.EtcdTestServer) {
etcdStorage, server := registrytest.NewEtcdStorage(t, "")
```

So this is limited by the **[limits of an ETCD](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/dev-guide/limit.html)**, not so much the number of entries, but rather the storage *size*.